# unable to create generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I was trying to create a generic extension method using following code but it gives compile time error

```
public static class extentions<TSource, TResult>
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetWholeHerichy(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> KeySelector, Func<TSource, TResult> FKeySelector, TResult KeyElementid)
    {
        var k = source.Where(a => EqualityComparer<TResult>.Default.Equals(KeyElementid, KeySelector(a))).ToList();
        while(true)
        {
            var nextLevel = source.Where(a => k.Select(b => KeySelector(b)).Contains(FKeySelector(a)) && ! k.Select(b => KeySelector(b)).Contains(KeySelector(a)));
            if (nextLevel == null || nextLevel.Count() < 1)
                break;
            k.AddRange(nextLevel);
        }
        return k.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Error is

> Error 1   Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

if i removes `<TSource, TResult>` from `public static class extentions<TSource, TResult>` to make class non-generic then `TSource` and `TResult` became undefined in whole class

Comment: You need to make the methods generic: `GetWholeHerichy<TSource, TResult>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must "move" the generic types in the method signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetWholeHerichy<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> KeySelector, Func<TSource, TResult> FKeySelector, TResult KeyElementid)
```

exactly like the various `Enumerable.*` methods.